# Why is Legosi's fur whitish grey

Tags: anime-production, beastars

I watched the second season of *Beastars*, and during his training with Gohin to help Legosi stop craving prey, he has white fur. All the training has to do with predators' instincts. I don't know if I missed it or not when I was watching the show or not. When watching the opening, I noticed he has white fur, specifically the scenes when he's running after Haru and when he is standing next to her in the meadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In episode 16, Gouhin cuts Legosi's fur incredibly short at the beginning of his training, making it appear white. The change in appearence isn't shown until the next episode, and the haircut happens halfway through the previous episode, so it's pretty easy to miss.

Comment: Ah, alright, thanks for that. Also, welcome ThreadHazard to StackExchange.